# importing SVGLoader from three.js giving Gateaway on Vite

Tags: three.js

I am on vite / vue 3 typescript and tried to import SVG via three.js but following error pops up as soon as I import the **SVGLoader**

> http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/deps/three_examples_jsm_loaders_SVGLoader.js?v=96b3206a net::ERR_ABORTED 504 (Gateway Timeout)

```
import { SVGLoader } from "three/examples/jsm/loaders/SVGLoader";
```

Any idea whats causing the gateaway error?

Comment: I’ve never used Vite, but does anything show up when you point your browser to http://localhost:3000/node_modules/ ?

Comment: it's a blank page as expected and nothing extraordinary log error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like a Vite bug with module(package) import, according to this [github discusstion](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/discussions/7873); and I know for sure because I've come across similar kind of problem when using any kind of unpolished module packages in Vite.

Fortunately, `SVGLoader` itself is not dependent to any other packages except three.js, so I advise you to copy the [SVGLoader code](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/jsm/loaders/SVGLoader.js) and make it as your own `.ts` file to include in your project.